# Why doesn't my Python code see the imported discord.py module?

Tags: python, github, intellij-idea, discord

I'm trying to make my first Discord Bot using Python, and it works perfectly on my desktop Windows computer. I also have a laptop running Ubuntu that I cloned the repository to in Intellij that isn't working correctly. Because I'm using slightly different Python versions (3.6.1 vs 3.5.2), I set it up to ignore my `misc.xml` file since it includes a Project-JDK-Name. I manually recreated it on my laptop based on an autogenerated one from another project (3.5.2).

On the laptop, it underlines the `import discord` line and tells me it cannot find the module. I have installed it using `python3 -m pip install discord` and reinstallation tells me it already exists.

Based on this [link](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/228), I also tried running `python3` then `import discord` in cmd, and got no output, so I'm assuming it didn't have an error. Why, then, does my Python project not see the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ide might have been using a different python interpreter than the one you download discord.py to. You will need to change the sdk settings. Follow this tutorial: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html

> To configure Python interpreter for a Python module, follow these
> steps
>
> Open the Project Structure dialog (e.g. Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S).
>
> In the Project Structure dialog box, click Modules node under the Project
> Settings.
>
> In the Module  pane of the selected Python
> module, click the Dependencies tab.
>
> Click Module SDK drop-down list,
> and select the desired Python interpreter from the list of the
> previously configured available Python interpreters.
>
> If the interpreter you need is missing in the list of available
> interpreters, click New next to the Module SDK field, choose Python
> SDK from the pop-up menu, choose interpreter type (local, remote,
> etc.) and then select the desired executable.

Comment: My "Project SDK" is `Python 3.5.2 (filepath)`. Is it possible that the Discord module was installed to the wrong version of Python (3 or 2.7?)

By the way - Ctrl Shift Alt S opened up a Project Structure window and I didn't need to do any clicking around to see the Project SDK.

Comment: Since you said running `python3` and importing `discord` works, type typing `whereis python3` in the terminal. And use that path as the sdk for the `Project SDK`

Comment: Update - I found the Modules node (ignore comment above). The Module SDK is `Project SDK (Python3.5.2 (/usr/bin...))` where it should be `Python 3.5.2 (/usr/bin/...)`. The second one worked and didn't give any errors once I changed it.

Comment: One question - what is the difference between the Project SDK and the second one that I posted? Only the second one worked.

Comment: The Project SDK is for when you set the folder the files are in as a project, when you're doing something with them together, there's usually a hidden `.idea` folder in that folder. And a module is just a singular file.

Comment: Why is it an option as a Module SDK then?

Comment: The Module SDK changes the SDK setting for the .py file you selected. While the Project SDK changes the SDK setting for the whole project. The Module SDK setting will override the Project SDK setting if the module has a different SDK setting than the project's.