# Python: ModuleNotFound Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, module, python-import

I downloaded multiple modules (Discord API, cx_Freeze) (pip download, Windows 10) and now I wanted to use them.

But when I want to import them, it says there isn’t any module.

From my former Python using (before resetting computer) I‘ve added a **pycache** folder and it worked for one module. I‘m not able to reproduce it for other modules. What to do?

- I‘ve only one Python version (3.6.5) on PC.
- I‘ve checked the \site-packages folder and they‘re there.

Comment: Have you tried typing `pip freeze` in the terminal? Check if your module is there.

Comment: Also, since you have python 3.6.5, when u install a module use `pip3 install ...`

Comment: I‘ve used the list module thing from Python. They’re there

Comment: If that does not work, I recommend trying `python setup.py install`. If this does not work, python may not be on your PATH or there may be some other error.

Comment: Python seems to be in path ‘cause when I print sys.path there are shown multiple directories, that 3rd party module folder included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using python3 then try downloading the library using

> pip3 install libname

but if you are using python2 then install the library using

> pip2 install libname or just pip install libname

try with these command and reply

Comment: This didn’t work. I’m a bit despaired now, do you have an other idea?

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but uninstall what you tried to install with `pip uninstall ...`, then try `python -m install ...`. If that does not work, the only other thing I can think of it that you might have a project folder named discord (or the module name) in your current directory, and the program is trying to import that. (if this is the case, rename the folder) Otherwise, I am out of ideas :(

Comment: BTW, i also found this link, but you can decide whether it is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927296/why-doesnt-my-python-code-see-the-imported-discord-py-module

Comment: which os are you using for programming the module and can you just send me the import statement . Please.

Comment: As you see in the first message it‘s Windows 10.

Comment: ```from cx_Freeze import *```

Answer (score 0):

try installing your library using the command prompt in normal user and with the admin user so that you will get to know that what is happening and also if it is still not working then try installing the library into the same folder of your project using pip custom install command

```
pip install -t <direct directory> <package>
```

then use the import statement

For Example I used

```
pip2 install -t c:\Users\Nav\Desktop\projectss cx_freeze
```

then i imported the library using

```
#from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import cx_Freeze
from cx_Freeze import *
```

it worked.
Previously i was getting error like :

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from cx_Freeze.finder import *
ImportError: No module named finder
```

After custom install it is working

Comment: Thank you sooo much. It worked with that custom install command.

Comment: Okay , And if possible then plz give this question a like .